# Stack Snippets Appears to be Down

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

When running a snippet I am getting:

> Server Error in '/' Application. Runtime Error Description: An
>   application error occurred on the server. The current custom error
>   settings for this application prevent the details of the application
>   error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could,
>   however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be
>   viewable on remote machines, please create a `<customErrors>` tag within
>   a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the
>   current web application. This `<customErrors>` tag should then have its
>   "mode" attribute set to "Off".
>
> ```
> <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
>
> <configuration>
>     <system.web>
>         <customErrors mode="Off"/>
>     </system.web> </configuration>
> ```
>
> Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a
>   custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the
>   application's `<customErrors>` configuration tag to point to a custom
>   error page URL.
>
> ```
> <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
>
> <configuration>
>     <system.web>
>         <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
>     </system.web> </configuration>
> ```

Also the domain itself https://stacksnippets.net/ shows the same error.

[image]

Comment: This feels *very* ironic...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry about that, this should be back up and running.

Those darn gremlins have been running around resulting in a bit of havoc.

Comment: Please pay closer attention to your timezones in future! :-)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366505/stack-snippets-is-down-again