# Stack Snippets Is Down Again

Tags: support, bug, stack-snippets

https://stacksnippets.net/ is returning:

> 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you
>   are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Test:

```html
Hello World
```

Comment: It is working for me

Comment: it is down for me as well

Comment: For me it also works, can you share your location? It may be an issue with an ISP/DNS provider.

Answer (score -12):

> This code snippet works fine for me

I'd say [stack snippet](https://stacksnippets.net/) works well for me.

Here is my output:

> [image: Image Output]

```html
Hello World
```

---

> Possibly

There could be some other reason, I can see some people having problem and for some people it works fine (Fine with me)

> Moreover

Your question is a possible duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343509/stack-snippets-returning-a-503-service-unavailable-error)

Comment: I think the OP hopes for an answer that tells them their problem is fixed ... not a re-confirmation of what I already made them aware of in my first comment under the question.

Comment: Well , check the comments form the link I provided in last , it will maybe give a good solution

Comment: That is their previous report of a similar issue. And all their previous reports had a fix that required intervention of the SRE team. It might be location dependent, so we could advice the OP to move to a country with a reliable internet backbone ;)

Comment: But for future, actual duplicates, use the "flag" link under the question.

Comment: I tried to "flag" the question but I the button was not there and I don't have privilege too

Comment: @MasterDarkNight It could be a duplicate, but the fact that the error code is different 500 here instead of 503 there make it not very likely

Comment: That's why I  stated "possible" duplicate , not. "Exact"